# Subscript out of range error when deploying two work sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a rookie in VBA trying to play around between two worksheets under one workbook. Why the following codes keep giving me "Subscript out of range" error?

```
Sub mon()


Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim s As Double
Dim rep As String

For i = 1 To 10000

    If Worksheets("Holding Extract to Excel").Cells(i, 31).Value > 1 Then

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Monitor").Cells(i, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Holding Extract to Excel").Cells(i, 1).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Monitor").Cells(i, 2).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Holding Extract to Excel").Cells(i, 10).Value
    Worksheets("Monitor").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("Holding Extract to Excel").Cells(i, 31).Value

    k = k + Worksheets("Monitor").Cells(i, 3).Value

    End If

Next i

Dim Total As Range
Set Total = Range(Cells(1, 5))

Worksheets("Monitor").Range("Total").Value = k


End Sub
```

Comment: At first glance, this doesn't look right to me `Set Total = Range(Cells(1, 5))`. You probably just want `Cells(1,5)`

Comment: Reconfirm if your workbook has the sheets `Holding Extract to Excel` or `Monitor`. Also manually check if there are no leading or trailing spaces in the names. " Monitor" is not the same as "Monitor"

Comment: Also, `Range("Total")` do you have a `named range` called "Total"? Or you meant by the last three lines `Worksheets("Monitor").Cells(1, 5).Value = k` ?